# Access denied upon doing a GetDirectories() but Dir in Powershell works

Tags: sharepoint

I have a problem I hope someone might help me with.

I've created a custom action page where I among other things will scan a directory on a remote server for a set of directories, and inside those directories I am searching for a set of files.
However, when I execute the code on the production server I get an Access denied exception.
If I use the same code on my testserver (accessing the same remote server) it works just fine.

If I use powershell or explorer on the production server I can access the remote directory and files with no problems.

I am using the same account in all scenarios (if I print out Page.User.Identity.Name and SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName they are the same and equal to the account I use on the test server and the one I am logged on with on the production server when accessing the remote server from command line or explorer).

The code looks like this:

```
string user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.Remove(0,7);
string user_path = "\\\\srv\\share1\\subdir\\dir\\" + user;

// The line below will raise an exception on the production server.
foreach (string board_path in Directory.GetDirectories(user_path, "Board*")) {
   foreach (string board_file in Directory.GetFiles(board_path, "Board*.xml")) {
   .
   .
   }
}
```

I cant figure out why the code runs on the testserver but not on the production machine. I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help I can get.

/Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()!

/Fredrik